# Mac Server 10.6.8 - adding DNS forwarders - can't "rndc reload"

Tags: domain-name-system, mac

I am trying to set DNS forwarders for OpenDNS in `named.conf` file.  After editing and saving the file, I tried reloading the BIND config with command: `rndc reload`. However, I am getting the error:

```
rndc: connect failed: 127.0.0.1#953: connection refused
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: here's named.conf file, will post LISTEN results next ...

Comment: sh-3.2# nano named.conf

  GNU nano 2.0.6                File: named.conf                                        

        keys    { "rndc-key";    };
   };


options  {
        include "/etc/dns/options.conf.apple";

                /*
         * If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
         * to talk to, you might need to uncomment the query-source
         * directive below.  Previous versions of BIND always asked
         * questions using port 53, but BIND 8.1 uses an unprivileged
         * port by default.
         */
        // query-source address * port 53;

Comment: //forwarders { 208.67.222.222; 208.67.220.220 ; };
//...                             
 };
//
// a caching only nameserver config
//
logging {
        include "/etc/dns/loggingOptions.conf.apple";
};

// Public view read by Server Admin

include "/etc/dns/publicView.conf.apple";

// Server Admin declares all zones in a view. BIND therefore dictates
 // that all other zone declarations must be contained in views.

Comment: what does these commands do?sudo launchctl stop org.isc.named
sudo launchctl start org.isc.named

Answer (score 1):

It seems `rndc` is failing to connect to your BIND server on that interface/port.  Is it listening?

```
sudo lsof -i | grep LISTEN
```

You may need to look in the `controls` statement of your BIND config to see how or if it's setup.  Something *like* this:

```
controls {
    inet 127.0.0.1 allow { localhost; }
```

Is it the built-in **named**?  If so try to restart it this way:

```
sudo launchctl stop org.isc.named
sudo launchctl start org.isc.named
```

Answer (score 0):

BIND name server might be running at a different port then the default port 953.

Often it is running at port 54.

Your BIND name server reload command then becomes:

```
$ sudo rndc -p 54 reload
```